# Natural, free-range, not raised locally

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

What falls standing up and moves around laying down?

Comment: Why all the downvotes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer is

What falls standing up and moves laying down?

> Water fall
>
>  When the water falls are falling down the water looks like it is standing up, and when it moves, seems like its moving laying down.

Comment: That was fast! Your answer is correct, though it could come in any of its forms.

Comment: please use the spoiler tag >! on your answer line